# I cannot switch back to pgAdmin III's Database Designer's default font

Tags: pgadmin

I changed the default pgAdmin III's Database Designer's default font, which used to be `MS Shell Dlg 2`:

[image]

I cannot set it back to the default font, namely `MS Shell Dlg 2`. Why?

I don't see `MS Shell Dlg 2` in the list of available fonts:

[image]

Typing `MS Shell Dlg 2` myself does not work (it doesn't change the font):

[image]

Clicking on the "show more fonts" link also does show `MS Shell Dlg 2`:

[image]

Comment: what happens if you click the "show more fonts" link?

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks, MS Shell Dlg 2 is also not there. I guess that pgadmin is configured to use MS Shell Dlg 2 by default, and if the font isn't there just use some replacement.

Answer (score 0):

According to [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-ms-shell-dlg-and-ms-shell-dlg-2), MS Shell Dlg 2 and Tahoma look to be functionally equivalent:

> MS Shell Dlg 2 simply uses the Tahoma font regardless of language. The main advantage of Tahoma over Microsoft Sans Serif is that Tahoma has a native bold font face. Its main disadvantage is that older operating systems might not have it installed, and might substitute a less attractive font.

This would also explain why Tahoma is the option that's selected when you first open the font menu. I tried switching to a different font and then back to Tahoma and it looks the same as MS Shell Dlg 2.